# Как в Win Forms проект вставить Ribbon в стиле Windows 7?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте!

Можно ли в `Windows Forms` проектах на C++ использовать `Ribbon` в стиле Windows 7? Если да, то как это можно сделать?

P.S. Вариант с `mfc` не предлагать, т.к. там, во-первых, `Ribbon` старый, а во-вторых, не хочется связываться с `mfc`.

P.P.S. Желательно без использования платных компонент.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Самый разумный способ без использования MFC, который я видел - [Windows 7 Ribbon: The Time Has Come, Your Win32 Application Will Change](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/rib.aspx).

*Там вся разметка риббона грузится из xml-ки, которую можно сделать руками или, например, воспользоваться средством типа [Visual Ribbon Creator](http://www.turboirc.com/vrc/)*

Код примера на **codeproject** далеко не самый лучший, однако смысл понять помогает.

Вообще, конечно, писать GUI на С++ - это дело неблагодарное и сложное, в том же самом шарпе, например, все было бы намного проще.